# Heroku xpath NoSuchMethodError: org.jaxen.dom.DocumentNavigator.getInstance()

Tags: xml, tomcat, heroku, jstl, jspx

I am using jspx in tomcat on Heroku and am having an issue with the below code. The odd thing is that sometimes it will work so I am reasonably confident that the issue is related to the classloader and whatever Heroku has in their library vs what I have defined in my pom (maven). My pom has no conflicts and when I run it locally I never get this error but when I deploy it to Heroku it happens pretty often. Sometimes just restarting the dyno fixes it but more often it does not.

Does anyone have a solution to get around this issue. I have a Context Listener and am not above forcing a class to reload from a specific relative path but would prefer not to go that route if it is not necessary.

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:x="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"
    xmlns:tiles-el="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles-el">

[ERROR] 2016-12-07 16:20:43,108 org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag:926 - ServletException in '/WEB-INF/jspx/index.jspx': java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jaxen.dom.DocumentNavigator.getInstance()Lorg/jaxen/dom/DocumentNavigator;
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jspx/index.jspx at line 18

15:   <div class="dropdown">
16:   <button>Year</button>
17:   <ul id="nav" class="dropdown-menu">
18:   <x:forEach var="temp" select="$doc/home/content[@year]">
19:     <c:set var="temp2"><x:out select="$temp/@year" /></c:set>
20:     <c:choose>
21:       <c:when test="${temp2==curyear}">
```